# Vlookup like formula to search value with text string in a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to search the value in E1 within values in B2:B6 and get the corresponding letter from column A using Excel 365.

I´ve tried with this formula but it seems I'm not using correctly `TEXTSPLIT()` since the `MATCH()` function is getting error or wrong result.

```
E1: =MATCH(E1,TEXTSPLIT(B2:B6,",")*1,0)
```

| H1 | H2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1,6,8,9,11,27 |
| B | 2,10,14,21,22,23,24,26,33 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 4,7 |
| E | 12,13 |

Below the expected result in E3:H3 for different values to search in E1:H1. Thanks for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessary you need to use <kbd>TEXTSPLIT()</kbd> you can use the following formula as well:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH(","&E$1&",",","&$B$2:$B$6&","),$A$2:$A$6)
```

---

Or, with <kbd>BYCOL()</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=BYCOL(E1:H1,LAMBDA(α, LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH(","&α&",",","&$B$2:$B$6&","),$A$2:$A$6)))
```

---

Or, with <kbd>TEXTSPLIT()</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=TOCOL(IFS(IFERROR(--TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(","&$B$2:$B$6,",",SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN($B$2:$B$6)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B$2:$B$6,",",))+1))),","),"")=E$1,$A$2:$A$6),2)
```

---

**Note:** Why <kbd>TEXTSPLIT()</kbd> is not working as you are trying to achieve, it is because the function is designed to operate with individual text strings breakingdown them into rows & columns. When you pass an array as input the said function doesn't recognizes it as an array and assumes it as a single column of values and output the same while the rest is discarded.

---

Or, Using <kbd>TOROW()</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=TOROW(IF(1-ISERR(SEARCH(","&E$1&",",","&$B$2:$B$6&",")),$A$2:$A$6,p),2)
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=BYCOL(IF(1-ISERR(SEARCH(","&E1:H1&",",","&$B$2:$B$6&",")),A2:A6,""),CONCAT)
```

---

Or, why not in this way:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$6,XMATCH("*,"&E1&",*",","&$B$2:$B$6&",",2))
```

---

Or use <kbd>BYCOL()</kbd> to spill

```
=BYCOL(E1:H1,LAMBDA(α, INDEX($A$2:$A$6,XMATCH("*,"&α&",*",","&$B$2:$B$6&",",2))))
```

---

Comment: Sometimes I've read that you can get surprise the kind of help your can get in forums like this one. This is one of that times!!! Thanks so much for your help, explanation and different solutions shared. Not sure why, the only one that failed for me was `=BYCOL(IF(1-ISERR... ... A2:A6,""),CONCAT)`

Comment: Working on my end, ah it could be because of `Beta Channel` which you need to enable.